# As per setTimeout in a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I am trying to get my code to appear after some time with the setTimeOut, but I can not, already tried everything, my code is below:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
 if(document.all){}
else document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEMOVE);document.onmousemove=mouse;function mouse(e)
{if(navigator.appName=='Netscape'){xcurs=e.pageX;ycurs=e.pageY;}else{xcurs=event.clientX;ycurs=event.clientY;}
document.getElementById('mime').style.left=(xcurs-230)+'px';document.getElementById('mime').style.top=(ycurs-150)+'px';}
</script>

</head>
<div id="mime">
<iframe style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:605px; height:250px;

float:left;" frameborder="0" scrolling="No" src="http://example.com/qaksC"></iframe>
</div>
```

I've tried:

```
setTimeout('document.getElementById('mime')', 60000);
document.getElementById('mime').setTimeout(60000);
```

I have tried various other things, but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Correct way of using setTimeout is as below

```
setTimeout(function(){
    document.getElementById('mime');
}, 60000);
```

Comment: Hello, I tried this:  <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
 if(document.all){}
else document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEMOVE);document.onmousemove=mouse;function mouse(e)
{if(navigator.appName=='Netscape'){xcurs=e.pageX;ycurs=e.pageY;}else{xcurs=event.clientX;ycurs=event.clientY;}
document.getElementById('mime').style.left=(xcurs-230)+'px';document.getElementById('mime').style.top=(ycurs-150)+'px';}
setTimeout(function(){
    document.getElementById('mime');
}, 60000);
</script>  but I could not: /

Comment: Can you please create a fiddle